# How to replace a word in a string if it contains any words from an array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, contains

I'd like to find and replace any word(s) in a string that match any string value in an array. I can find the matching value using *.contains(where*:

```
var playersApprovedArray = ["Monica","Zach","Chrissy"]
card.cardText = "Chrissy, do 10 jumping jacks right now!"

if playersApprovedArray.contains(where: card.cardText.contains) {

print("Found matching player in card text")

// Replace the matching word/player here with another word/player

}
```

But I don't know how to replace the occurrence of the matching word with another string value in the array.

Comment: you can use collection method `index(where:)`

Comment: This question is very similar to the one marked as duplicate, but it'is different because a *different player* has to be inserted

Comment: There's no functional difference between "replace with an arbitrary string" and replace with an empty string".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple solution that replaces one player with another:

```
for i in playersApprovedArray.indices {
    let player = playersApprovedArray[i]
    if let range = cardText.range(of: player) {
        let otherIndex = (i + Int.random(in: 1..<playersApprovedArray.count)) % playersApprovedArray.count
        let otherPlayer = playersApprovedArray[otherIndex]
        cardText.replaceSubrange(range, with: otherPlayer)
        break
    }
}
```

You can remove the `break` if the sentence may contains more *players*.

---

Here is a faster solution that would replace all occurrences of any player's name by another:

```
let playersApprovedArray = ["Monica","Zach","Chrissy"]
let cardText = " Chrissy, do 10 jumping jacks right now! "

var result = ""

var i = cardText.startIndex

while i < cardText.endIndex {
    var j = i
    while j < cardText.endIndex,
        CharacterSet.letters.inverted.isSuperset(of: CharacterSet(charactersIn: String(cardText[j])))
        {
        j = cardText.index(after: j)
    }

    var tempo1 = ""
    if i != j { tempo1 += cardText[i..<j] }

    if j < cardText.endIndex { i = j } else {
        result += tempo1
        break
    }

    while j < cardText.endIndex,
        CharacterSet.letters.isSuperset(of: CharacterSet(charactersIn: String(cardText[j])))
        {
        j = cardText.index(after: j)
    }

    let tempo2 = String(cardText[i..<j])

    if let index = playersApprovedArray.firstIndex(of: tempo2) {
        let otherIndex = (index + Int.random(in: 1..<playersApprovedArray.count)) % playersApprovedArray.count
        let otherPlayer = playersApprovedArray[otherIndex]
        result += tempo1 + otherPlayer
        //See comment below for possible early exit
    } else {
        result += tempo1 + tempo2
    }

    i = j
}

print(result)  // Monica, do 10 jumping jacks right now!
```

If you're sure that there is only one *player* in the string, then you can exit early this way:

```
        ...
        result += tempo1 + otherPlayer + cardText[j...]
        break
        ...
```

Comment: Spectacular, thank you! I haven't tried the faster solution as I'd like to go through it and understand it better, but the simple solution (with the removal of the break, as there is circumstances with multiple players) works to perfection.